# Uniqueness of the ODE solution

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

There is a system $$\frac{dx}{dt} = y^{3}+ ln(t+1) , \
x\frac{dy}{dt}=(y-t)^{\frac{1}{3}}$$
It has the only solution by the Cauchy – Kovalevskaya theorem under the following initial conditions:
$$t_{0}>-1, \ x_{0}\neq 0, \ y_{0}\neq t_{0}$$
Will the system have the only solution if $$y_{0}=t_{0}$$ (other initial conditions will not change)  ?

Comment: P.S
the theorem guarantees that if  y0≠t0 the system exactly has a unique solution, if y0=t0 nothing is known.

Comment: Do you have any ideas?